# Should I set field size and input validation for Access 2016 form column?

Tags: validation, ms-access

Created a table and form that has an input for Location ID that is set for must be 12 characters (Numbers only) of (Short text data type) which I set using input validation and alert text. Are there any performance losses leaving the field size at 255 or should this match the input validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no performance losses leaving the field size at 255.